# Keycloak / Nodejs integration raise 400 Bad Request

Tags: node.js, keycloak

I'm evaluating Keycloak integration to secure the access of a Nodejs API. I followed different tutorials such as:

- [Keycloak documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_nodejs_adapter)
- [Keycloak quick start](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/latest/service-nodejs/)

But I'm facing an issue while restricting access to a route with a specific role.

I created a realm named '**tst**', a client named '**tst-api**' with the following URLs:

- redirect URL: http://localhost:3000/*
- web origins URL: http://localhost:3000

client is configured with client authentication, standard flow and direct access grant capabilities.

I created two realm Roles: **realm-tst-user** and **realm-tst-admin** and also two client roles: **client-tst-user** and **client-tst-admin**

I associated client roles to realm roles:

- client-tst-user -> realm-tst-user
- client-tst-admin -> realm-tst-admin

and I create a user with a role mapping set to 'realm-tst-user'

I'm able to generate a token with CURL command:

```
curl -X POST 'http://localhost:8080/realms/tst/protocol/openid-connect/token' \
 --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
 --data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' \
 --data-urlencode 'client_id=tst-api' \
 --data-urlencode 'client_secret=<SECRET_FROM_CLIENT_CREDENTIALS>' \
 --data-urlencode 'username=user' \
 --data-urlencode 'password=1234'
```

So I assume everything is ok for this. Then, I implemented a very basic node API based on the tutorial mentioned just above:

My index.js is the following:

```
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const Keycloak = require('keycloak-connect');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Enable CORS support
app.use(cors());

const memoryStore = new session.MemoryStore();

app.use(session({
  secret: 'session',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  store: memoryStore
}));

const keycloak = new Keycloak({
  store: memoryStore
});

app.use(keycloak.middleware({
  logout: '/logout',
  admin: '/'
}));

app.get('/service/public', function (req, res) {
  res.json({message: 'public'});
});

app.get('/service/secured', keycloak.protect('client-wib-user'), function (req, res) {
  res.json({message: 'secured'});
});

app.get('/service/admin', keycloak.protect('client-wib-admin'), function (req, res) {
  res.json({message: 'admin'});
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Started at port 3000');
});
```

And keycloak.json is the following:

```
{
"realm": "tst",
"auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8080/",
"ssl-required": "external",
"resource": "tst-api",
"verify-token-audience": true,
"credentials": {
  "secret": "<SECRET_FROM_CLIENT_CREDENTIALS>"
},
"use-resource-role-mappings": true,
"confidential-port": 0,
"policy-enforcer": {}
}
```

When I try to access a secured API endpoint such as http://localhost:3000/service/secured, it ask me to login with Keycloak login page and when logged-in, I have the following display on the screen:

> Access Denied

on Node console I have the following message

```
Could not obtain grant code: Error: 400:Bad Request
```

and on Keycloak logs

```
type=CODE_TO_TOKEN_ERROR, realmId=xxxxxx, clientId=tst-api, userId=yyyyyy, ipAddress=172.17.0.1, error=invalid_code, grant_type=authorization_code, code_id=zzzzzz, client_auth_method=client-secret
```

I also tried to protect access to routes by using realm role instead of client roles (realm-tst-user, realm-tst-admin) but the result is the same...

I do not see what's wrong in my config, I tried also other tutorials but there's nothing different from what I did, any idea ?

on the other hand, how can I change the Access Denied HTML page displayed to the end user as it seems to be generated by Keycloak middleware ?

Comment: Which version of Keycloak is running?

Comment: keycloak.protect('client-wib-user') means user has a role in `tst-api` client. So you needs to use user based permission check method by  keycloak.enforcer(['resource:scope'], {
  resource_server_id: 'tst-api'
}. The best reference is [example](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-nodejs-connect/tree/main/example)

Comment: I'm using release 20.0.3